# MvxBind fails: functions are declared but there is source not found error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono, mvvmcross

Been trying to bind click function to ListView element, but keep getting this error (and nothing even is shown in the screen):

> I/mono-stdout(1960): MvxBind:Warning: 13.07 Unable to bind: source
>   property source not found Property:ItemClick on ListMenuViewModel

Can't figure out what wrong here

The layout with bindings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/messagesList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ListItems; ItemClick OnItemClick"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My viewmodel:

```
public class ListMenuViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        private IAudioDataHandlerService _audioDataHandlerService;
        private IToastService _toastService;

        private ObservableCollection<ListMenuItemDto> _listItems;
        public ObservableCollection<ListMenuItemDto> ListItems
        {
            get { return _listItems; }
            set
            {
                _listItems = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ListItems);

            }
        }

        public ListMenuViewModel(IAudioDataHandlerService audioDataHandlerService, IMvxNavigationService mvxNavigationService, IToastService toastService)
        {
            _audioDataHandlerService = audioDataHandlerService;
            _mvxNavigationService = mvxNavigationService;
            _toastService = toastService;
        }
        public override void ViewAppeared()
        {
            base.ViewAppeared();

            // do some test stuff
            var data = _audioDataHandlerService.GetAllItems();
            ListItems = new ObservableCollection<ListMenuItemDto>(data.Result);
        }

        private async Task DisplayToastMessage(ListMenuItemDto item)
        {
           await _toastService.ShowToastMessage(item.Subtext + "#" + item.Text);
        }

        public IMvxAsyncCommand<ListMenuItemDto> OnItemClick
        {
            get
            {
                MvxAsyncCommand<ListMenuItemDto> navigationCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand<ListMenuItemDto>(DisplayToastMessage);
                return navigationCommand;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD**

For some resaon it works now, wonder why
[image]

Comment: @mjwills `OnItemClick` property which is suppose to be called

Comment: @mjwills oh, thx, I see now, maybe it didn't rebuild it after latest changes. strange, cuz MvxListView AFAIK suppose to have an `ItemClick` property, at least in examples around web in the layouts

Comment: @mjwills well, it works now and IDK why, see my update